# 60s-70s novel written from a werewolf's point of view

Tags: story-identification, novel

Long ago I read a paperback novel that was written before 1981 (I'm guessing sometimes in the 60s or 70s).

The story was written from the main character's point of view, who was a human male who could transform into a werewolf.  When in wolf form, the author described what the wolf was feeling, such as the scent of a rabbit, a cow in estrus, and the feeling of speed and power as he moved through the fields.

Comment: Those are fairly common tropes in werewolf novels. Do you recall anything about the plot?

Comment: The only detail I remember from the plot was the description of the wolf catching and eating a wild rabbit.  I read it many moons ago :-)

Comment: You might try "The Orphan" by Robert Stallman. It's a bite late - 1980 - but the first person male main character does a lot of describing of his animal senses.

Comment: "The Orphan" may be the one I am looking for.  I ordered a used copy on Amazon, will be here in a few weeks.

Comment: The picture on the cover also rings a few old memories, I think "The Orphan" is it.

Comment: Glad to help! Finally, my encyclopedic knowledge of werewolf novels comes in handy ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Posting this, since I got it in the comments: Robert Stallman, “The Orphan”, published 1980. It's a bite late, but the first person male main character does a lot of describing of his animal senses.

From [Goodreads](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/950179.The_Orphan):

> The werewolf is a creature of the night, a solitary, fur-covered thing. A wild-eyed, five clawed beast with a taste for blood and the soft crunch of bone between the teeth. But as little Robert, the werewolf has been adopted by a kindly farmer and his wife. Neither Robert nor the monster could control the shifting of its form, and always, the emerged beast lurked within, ready to spring for the throat.

Answer (score 3):

This book was written in 1989, but it may be the one you are looking for: *[The Wolf's Hour](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Wolf%27s_Hour)* by Robert R. McCammon.

It is a first-person account of a werewolf allied secret agent during WW2. The narrative includes his memories of being bitten and transitioning from human to werewolf, his time with the pack, and his experiences in both human and wolf form after leaving the pack and becoming a well-paid and highly regarded (and secretly a) werewolf operative from North Africa to France.

Answer (score 3):

George R. R. Martin has a short story/novella called [*The Skin Trade*](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?48331) (1988). I understand this may be a far shot, but I think it was worth keeping the info here, in case it helps.

One of the main characters of the story is a male werewolf. At the beginning of the story, he is transformed into wolf-form and everything is described through his enhanced senses.

The other main character is a female police officer, best fried of the (unknown to her) werewolf guy and whose father, who was also a police officer, was brutally murdered by what seemed to be a werewolf.

Together they will investigate the murder of a friend of the werewolf guy, who was skinned alive.

Comment: @user14111, agree, thus my note at the end of the post. It is just to be considered (and probably discarded) by the OP.